# Python: change CWD of script bundled with py2app

Tags: python, py2app

My script works fine when ran with `python`, but after I build it with `py2app`, files and folders are created in `.app/Contents/Resources`. I use `os.getcwd()` to find out where the script is located.

How can I fix this and make sure my files are created in the app containing directory?

**Hacky fix**

Here's a hack that works:

```
if re.search('([^/]+$)', cwd).group(0) == "Resources":
    mkFldr(cwd[0:-27] + fldr)         #this is a try except function
    sanExt(extPath, str(cwd[0:-27] + fldr + "/" + extName + "_san.csv"))
else:
    mkfldr(fldr)
    sanExt(extPath, str(cwd + "/" + fldr + "/" + extName + "_san.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly I use something similar to the following to handle this. The 'frozen' part changes the behaviour depending on whether you're running the script or a py2exe/py2app executable.

```
import sys
import os.path

frozen = getattr(sys, 'frozen', '')

if frozen:
    MyFolder = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    Myfolder = os.getcwd()
```